# Unix/Linux terminal, How to display specific letters followed by other letters?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

I created a file via Linux terminal and named it people, the contents of this file are as follows..

```
Mr. Smith
Mrs. Jenn Bewlite
Ms Carmichael
Dr Ivan James
Mrs Holly Alva Beswol
Mrs James Sheepwool
Mr. Hitchcock
```

How do I display lines that have the letter `H` followed later on the line by the letter `o`.

I have tried to use the following commands, but it didn't work.. maybe I have a typo.

```
$ egrep -w 'H|o' /home/liveuser/people
$ grep "H|o" people
```

Comment: Do you want lines where `H` is followed _immediately_ by `o`, or by `o` after any number of intervening characters?

Comment: Lines where H is followed by o after any number of intervening characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a typo. What you are trying to do is called
"regular expressions".

> How do I display lines that have the letter H followed later on the line by the letter o.

I assume you want to match H case insensitive, with any characters following until the character "o". Please post a comment to correct me if I've misunderstood.

```
grep -i "h.*o" /home/liveuser/people
```

This will do the trick in your case.

*You can replace `/home/liveuser/people` with whatever path you want. I see you try to use just "people" which is fine if your current directory is /home/liveuser*

*Note that you can use "egrep" too.*

### Explanation

The `-i` flag makes grep case insensitive 
As for the `"h.*o"` there are 4 things going on:

1. The "h" matches the character "h"
2. The "." matches **any** character. (Except for newline)
3. The "*" makes it so that the previous character or expression is matched multiple times. In this case it matches any amount of characters that isn't newline
4. The "o" makes sure that we have an "o" after the "h" with any characters in between.

A link to a page explaining regex in grep: [Regular Expressions in grep](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong regexp syntax. Use `H.*o`, not `H|o`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
$ grep "H.*o" foo
Mrs Holly Alva Beswol
Mr. Hitchcock
```

Comment: Thank you this is the write answer.

Comment: If you don't quote the regex, it'll expand to filenames matching the glob `H.*o`, like `H.ao` and `H.aaaaao`, and there probably won't be a grep match for that. It'll also expand to multiple strings if there is more than one matching filename.